# How to put a glyphicon inside the bootstrap popover content in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

I want to include a glyphicon next to the content of my popover and it will be done dynamically in jquery.
But when I add the span tags for the glyphicon, it shows the html string when the popover is displayed. It doesn't translate it to html

```
$(this).attr("data-content", "<span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></span>You can't unlist if you have upcoming events scheduled" );
```

The content ends up looking like this in the popover

```
"<span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></span>You can't unlist if you have upcoming events scheduled"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Per Bootstrap Docs, if you need to set `data-content` dynamically then it should not be specified as a attribute.

Try This,

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <h3>Popover Example</h3>
  <a href="#" data-toggle="popover" title="Popover Header">Toggle popover</a>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
    html:true,
    content:function(){
    return ("<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-user'>Hello</span>");
    },
    });   
});
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DChandraShekhar/zy9bfsj9/6/)

Hope this Helps..

Answer (score -2):

Try using single quotes around the glyphicon code:

```
$(this).attr("data-content",'<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign" 
aria-hidden="true"></span>You can't unlist if you have upcoming events 
scheduled');
```